# Definition of analytically unramified rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> A noetherian local ring $A$ is said to be *analytically* *unramified* if the complete local ring $\hat{A}$ is reduced.

I don't see why it makes sense to call such a ring analytically unramified. The only possibility is, I guess, that $A \to \hat{A}$ is unramified ; meaning $\Omega_{\hat{A}/A} = 0$. But I don't see why $\hat{A}$ reduced would be equivalent to $\Omega_{\hat{A}/A} = 0$.

**EDIT** : if $A$ is already complete and non-reduced then the map $A \to \hat{A}$ is the identity so it is unramified.

So please, let me know why we use that definition...

Comment: Is $A$ reduced ?

Comment: $A \to \widehat{A}$ is injective. So if $\widehat{A}$ is reduced, then so is $A$.

Comment: Yes I know. But then a complet non-reduced local ring is not analytically unramified. I checked this in Matsumura and I find the definition a little strange. Anyway, in this situation, the $\Omega$ vanishes, but $A$ is not analytically unramified.

Comment: Ho nice ! If $A$ is complete non-reduced then $A \to \widehat{A}$ is the identity so it is unramified. Ok. So then, when this definition ?

Comment: If $A$ is a discrete valuation ring, then $A$ is analytically unramified, but I suspect that $\Omega_{\hat{A}/A}$ is non-zero if $A$ is not excellent as there will be inseparable elements in $\hat{A}$.

Comment: This terminology might just not be well choosen.

Comment: In the same time, a ring is said to be analytically irreducible if $\hat{A}$ is an integral domain. That definition makes perfect sense to me, for example.

Comment: But unramified is usually taken in the relative sense. Here the property is an absolute one.